# Delete folder displaying no messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a delete folder for the inbox messaging and the page remains blank. It should display messages the 'recipient_deleted'. The value in the database when the recipient deletes the message is 1 for column 'recipient_deleted'. The message will erase completely from the database when the sender deletes it also which will show a 1 for column 'sender_deleted'.

trash.html:

```
<% for message in @messages.recipient_deleted %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see the code is fine. Your page is showing up blank which means you need to render your delete folder. Create a `elsif params` for your inbox that points to the delete folder. Then render a partial for the delete folder. That should get the page to show.

Change:

```
<% for message in @messages.recipient_deleted %>
```

to

```
<% for message in @messages %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cornelius,

First, under deleted_messages, you're not scoping this to the specific user.

Second, I'm not sure if you have a relationship within your user and message models, but you should from the code you have posted. If you do not have a 'user_id' field within your message.rb model you should add it via a migration.

```
within app/models/user.rb
has_many :messages

within app/models/message.rb
belongs_to :user
```

The reason why this is important is that you will be able to write this code:

within user.rb

```
def deleted_messages
   messages.where(recipient_deleted: 1)
end

def sent_messages
   messages.where(sent_by: self.id)
end

def received_messages
   messages.where(received_by: self.id)
end
```

If you want to see a user's messages, after you have defined the relationship. You only need to write:

```
<<instance of user>>.messages
eg. current_user.messages
eg. @user.messages
```

Comment: Hey I wouldn't need a user id column for the messages table since I have sender_id and recipient_id. My inbox works fine as I coded it, I just can't seem to get the delete folder going.

Comment: The reason why you can't seem to get the delete folder going is 'How would you?'

I would look into using a foreign_key so that you can access the specific user's messages. Your Message.recipient deleted is acting on the class, not even on an array of all of the messages. 

Look here to define a foreign key: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

You can try something like this Message.where(received_by: self.id).where(recipient_deleted: 1) but its not a good practice.